# Show the first pickerView row on the screen when I'm back the page

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to get the first row data for pickerView.

I'm getting first data when I'm back the pickerView page, but I'm getting the wrong row on the screen. This is how I'm getting the first row :

```
pickerView(myPickerView!, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
```

I'm using this code in viewDidLoad. How can I show the first row on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

u may use the func pickerView(pickerView:

```
UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
```

have a look at [this article](https://makeapppie.com/2014/10/21/swift-swift-formatting-a-uipickerview/)

Comment: I looked this article and tried it before, but It's not working or I don't figure out.

Comment: what do you mean with " but I'm getting the wrong row **on the screen**"? Maybe, you must use a Delegate to inform **another** VC? Then u can use this in the didSelectRow

Comment: I did with viewForRow. Something is missing on article, but handle it. Thank you so much. Btw I don't need a didselectrow. I'll explain with my solution answer.

Comment: happy that i could help you!

Answer (score 1):

please use this code to select a particular row,

```
let picker = UIPickerView()
picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

Comment: Yeah It's working to show the first row, but not not selecting. I see the first row, but It's not selected the first row data behind back.

Comment: can u provide me the screen shot

Comment: I have forgotten to get data sorry. I used this code in viewForRow function, but it's very slow because it is animating. I found a solution with your answers. I'll write my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I give up to get first picker row data when I come back the page. I think it should be the selected row data I should get. I combined your solutions and find the solve.

Working code :

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    let titleData = newuser!.valueForKey("name").objectAtIndex(row) as! String
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 25.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
    pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .Center

    selectedLog = (newuser?.valueForKey("name").objectAtIndex(row))! as! String

    return pickerLabel
}
```

This `viewForRow` function provides me to get selected row data when I come back the `pickerView` page. `selectedLog` is my string variable. I show and save the selected row data from here. `titleData` variable provides me to get selected data. That's it! Thanks all of you.